# Bash: Regex for comparing file path

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, test

I want to check if an input string matches whitelisted file paths, then only I want to perform some operation.

I am doing something like this

```
path1="mydir/**"
path2="mydir/testing"

[ [ "$path2" =~ "$path1" ] ] && echo "Matches"
```

Where, if paths are like

```
mydir/test/dir
mydir/othertest/dir
```

These should pass.

Above check is giving me an error

```
assets/bin/copymain: line 8: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: I am all new to regex and bash scripting. I apologise for any silly mistakes.

Comment: So you want to check that it contains `test` not `testing`?  Or do you want to check that the path is exactly one of a hard set list of paths?  Where does the input string come from?

Comment: There would be an array of whitelisted paths, this is just an example. If whitelisted path is `mydir/test/**`, then `mydir/anything` should not get passed. Input string would be generated from other function.

Comment: AFAIK `[ [` and `] ]` aren't valid bash syntax: there's `[ .. ]` and then there's `[[ ... ]]`. Also, enclosing the RHS argument of `=~` in quotes will cause it to be treated as a string not a regex.

Comment: That syntax resembles [.gitignore files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). That regex version is quite complex to port to bash. Do you need full support for it, or only the '**' scenario?

Comment: I mainly need to compare '**' and '*.txt' (or any extension), these two scenarios are required.

Comment: @steeldriver Even if I remove spaces, same problem is happening. I changed my code to `[$([ $path2 =~ $path1 ])] && echo "Matches"` and I am getting error `assets/bin/copymain: line 8: [: =~: binary operator expected`

Comment: `[$([` is not `[[`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net will get you a decent way to fixing your code syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
path1="mydir/**"
path2="mydir/testing"
```

Here `path1="mydir/**"` uses a globbing pattern witch is a totally different language than the Extended RegEx used in the comparison.

`[ [ "$path2" =~ "$path1" ] ] && echo "Matches"`

But the conditions uses a RegEx:

`[[ "$path2" =~ "$path1" ]]`

Do not add spaces between the `[ [` and `] ]` but `[[` and `]]`

Parameter expansion globbing and Regex are two different pattern languages.

If `$path1` contains the whitelist pattern, then you must write it in RegEx like this:

```
path1='^mydir/'
path2="mydir/testing"

[[ ${path2} =~ ${path1} ]] && echo "Matches"
```

The right side is the RegEx variable `path1` and it must not be quoted, as that would cause regexp operators (such as `^` above) to be taken literally (unless you set the `compat31` option or set `BASH_COMPAT=3.1`).

Answer (score 1):

Note if only requirement is to compare paths/strings that end or start certain way, then regular expressions are not needed:

```
d1=mydir/test/dir
d2=mydir/othertest/dir
d3=mydir-2/test/dir-2

[[ "$d1" == mydir/* ]] && echo matches
[[ "$d2" == mydir/* ]] && echo matches
[[ "$d3" != mydir/* ]] && echo no-match

[[ "$d1" == */dir ]] && echo matches
[[ "$d2" == */dir ]] && echo matches
[[ "$d3" != */dir ]] && echo no-match
```